# Ubuntu 16.04: Wifi does not scan networks

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 after having issues with my wifi in Ubuntu. Even after reinstalling, the wifi showed "Wifi is disabled" error.

I followed this link: [Install Ralink RT3290 Wi-Fi driver on Ubuntu 15.04 based distributions](http://onthim.blogspot.in/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html)

& downloaded and installed this driver: [RT3290_u16 Driver](http://www.mediafire.com/file/pu4rejmmft8z9yr/RT3290_u16_v1.tar.gz)

My wifi eventually was enabled but then it is unable to scan any wifi networks.

There are no scan results when I run this command:

```
sudo iwlist rename3 scan
```

rename3 is the logical name of my wireless.

Here is the output of

```
sudo lshw -C network

 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: rename3
   version: 00
   serial: 9c:d2:1e:4e:e0:29
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
   resources: irq:18 memory:b5510000-b551ffff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 08
   serial: a0:2b:b8:49:1c:cf
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=10.8.40.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable help!